# Android camera unexplainable rotation on capture for some devices (not in EXIF)

Tags: android, camera, rotation, orientation, capture

What I'm doing seems like it should be simple, but I'm still lost after I've read every possible Stackoverflow answer I can find and Googled every article I can find.

I'm using a preview SurfaceView and capturing an image from an activity that is set for screenOrientation="landscape" in my AndroidManifest.xml.

I followed the sample Camera app code and thought things were working until I tried my app on a few Motorola devices running 1.5.

I have the OrientationEventListener running OK and I use reflection to see if set the rotation as such:

```
final int latchedOrientation = roundOrientation(mLastOrientation + 90);

Parameters parameters = preview.camera.getParameters();

JPLog.d("Setting camera rotation = %d", latchedOrientation);
try {
    // if >= 2.0
    Method method = Camera.Parameters.class.getMethod("setRotation",
        int.class);

    if(method != null) {
        method.invoke(parameters, latchedOrientation);
    }

} catch(Throwable t) {
    // if < 2.0
    parameters.set("rotation", latchedOrientation);
}

preview.camera.setParameters(parameters);
```

**NexusOne (OS 2.2)** - Works great.  latchedOrientation = 0, picture OK without any rotation in the EXIF header.

**T-Mobile G1 (OS 1.6)** - Also works great.  latchedOrientation = 0, picture OK.

**Motorola Backflip (OS 1.5)** - Image rotated.  latchedOrientation = 0, picture has no EXIF rotation in it.

**Motorola CLIQ (OS 1.5)** - Image rotated.  latchedOrientation = 0, picture has no EXIF rotation in it.

What's going on with these Motorola devices?  I thought my problem was the Motorola camera driver wasn't rotating the images, so found the Sanselan EXIF reading classes for Android and was preparing to rotate them myself.  Funny thing is, there is EXIF headers but no rotation element.

If I set the rotation manually to 90 degrees, the images come out perfect the Motorola devices, but now the G1 and the NexusOne have images that are rotated 90 degrees (not what I want).  There has to be something I'm not getting here.

I'm doubting this is a 1.5 issue, or else someone would've posted info on it?

Comment: Answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14066038/why-image-captured-using-camera-intent-gets-rotated-on-some-devices-in-android

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is actually a device-specific issue that mostly affects Motorola devices.  The google devs included a **[setDisplayOrientation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setDisplayOrientation(int))** call in API 8 to work around the issue.  The main bug is filed [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1193).

For those that can't go to API 8, the two common solutions are:

**Override onDraw**
Override onDraw in a top-level ViewGroup and rotate the canvas by 90 degrees to compensate for the rotation.  Note there is a caveat here as your touch events will also need to be rotated.

**Use Landscape Mode**
Lock the activity to landscape mode but draw assets as if they are in portrait.  This means you do your layout and rotate your image assets to look like you are in portrait mode so that the view looks normal.  This unfortunately makes it difficult to use the menu since the menu will open horizontally.

I have also seen people use an animation controller to rotate the view.  The drawback here that I wasn't able to overcome is that the rotated view doesn't stretch to fill the screen.  See the [answer by Georg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444764/rotate-view-hierarchy-90-degrees/4624242#4624242) for a sample implementation.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no good way to do it and it looks like there's a bug in the Moto camera drivers.

Comment: It works for me in the Motorola drivers. I just replace this line: mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90); by function "http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setDisplayOrientation(int)" with cameraid = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT

Answer (score 47):

I had this issue and I used this method to capture the image. (Without creating a custom camera)

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(image));
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

and did the rest in onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {}

But the original image (Actual SD card image) was correct and Bitmap was rotated when I fetched like this.
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(..

The solution:

```
    try {
        File f = new File(SD_CARD_IMAGE_PATH);
        ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(f.getPath());
        int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

        int angle = 0;

        if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90) {
            angle = 90;
        } 
        else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180) {
            angle = 180;
        } 
        else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) {
            angle = 270;
        }

        Matrix mat = new Matrix();
        mat.postRotate(angle);

        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, null);
        Bitmap correctBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), mat, true);                 
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.w("TAG", "-- Error in setting image");
    }   
    catch(OutOfMemoryError oom) {
        Log.w("TAG", "-- OOM Error in setting image");
    }
```

Comment: Great solution, I just improved it a bit as in the case of `angle = 0` there is no need to decode it and create a second bitmap with a rotation of 0. This should, in case of running on a not effected device, reduce the memory consumption by 50% for this process.

Comment: Struggled for a while with rotation method since on some device when tacking photo in portrait mode simple rotation makes image stretched. The solution found was: `code 
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postTranslate(-width / 2, -height / 2);
        matrix.postRotate(angle);
        matrix.postTranslate(width / 2, height / 2); `

Answer (score 4):

Here is the code I used onActivityResult() in my activity.  The intent returned was for picking an image of the type image/*.  Works well for me!

```
Uri imageUri = intent.getData();
                String[] orientationColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.ORIENTATION};
                Cursor cur = managedQuery(imageUri, orientationColumn, null, null, null);
                int orientation = -1;
                if (cur != null && cur.moveToFirst()) {
                    orientation = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(orientationColumn[0]));
                }  
                Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                matrix.postRotate(orientation);
```

Comment: I need to capture the image within my app and setting the params like in the snippet I posted in the question.  It would however be easier if I could fire off an intent to have another app take the picture for me.

Comment: You can still use this on the URI where your app stores images taken with the camera.  This is just code to rotate an image to the correct orientation with a URI.  Doesn't matter where its from.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the 'use landscape mode' suggestion is the only thing that really works. It seems that it's ok for this to be in either the manifest, or done via a call to `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)` in the activity onCreate.