# Problem with the android camera

Tags: android, camera

I'm building an application in android which uses the camera.I have built my own camera but the problem is that once I open my camera this way:

```
 public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        Log.e(TAG, "surfaceCreated");
        mCamera = Camera.open();

    }
```

Both my preview and the picture taken are rotated 90 degrees when the phone is in `portrait` mode, when the phone is turned in the landscape mode everything looks great.Does anyone know how could this be solved.

Thank you!

Comment: There was an accepted answer for this kind of question. Probably you want to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852154/android-camera-unexplainable-rotation-on-capture-for-some-devices-not-in-exif/4939319#4939319) out.

Comment: I had asked the same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645960/how-to-set-android-camera-orientation-properly

Comment: BUT HOW DID U DO THAT???I read your accepted answer...

Answer (score 0):

setRotation(int rotation) of [Camara.Parameters](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html) is your friend here.

Edit:

Did you see the reference code in the docs :

```
public void public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
     if (orientation == ORIENTATION_UNKNOWN) return;
     android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info =
            new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
     android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
     orientation = (orientation + 45) / 90 * 90;
     int rotation = 0;
     if (info.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
         rotation = (info.orientation - orientation + 360) % 360;
     } else {  // back-facing camera
         rotation = (info.orientation + orientation) % 360;
     }
     mParameters.setRotation(rotation);
 }
```