# viewpager imageview zoomin/zoomout landscape capture photo display not full width of imageview

Tags: java, android

I am using viewpager to view every single photo inside imageview using [this](https://github.com/a85/WebComicViewer/blob/master/src/com/rickreation/ui/ZoomableImageView.java) :-

```
ZoomableImageView imageView = new ZoomableImageView(context);
 Bitmap bimage=  getBitmapFromURL(test);
 imageView.setBitmap(bimage);

public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
          try {

              URL url = new URL(src);
              HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
              connection.setDoInput(true);
              connection.connect();
              InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
              Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

              return myBitmap;
          } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();

              return null;
          }
      }
```

the problem I am facing right now is that when i take photo in landscape mode and view the photo in landscape, the photo in imageview is not shown in  full width of the devices. But when i capture it in portrait mode, it comes in full size and in  landscape, it is not full size but centralized correctly. i wants to show full width for landscape photo just like the android native gallery.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: for image capture are you calling the default camera via intent or your own code ie using Surface view.......

Comment: @SivaK for image capture i m calling via intent and save in onactivityresult

Comment: i think that is the problem. in android each manufacturers have their own type of camera capturing style. You need to rotate the captured image and save it in another path and then u have to use it.....

Comment: check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8346955/android-camera-resulted-image-should-be-rotated-after-the-capture