# How to rotate the layout?

Tags: android

I have made 1 layout and I want to rotate the whole view to 180 degree.

Please help me how to do this

Thanks,
Monali

Comment: by rotating do you mean to change the orientation of the application like vertical/horizontal

Comment: yes rahul but i want to rotate the specific layout only..please help

Comment: have look at the link provided by Deva it will surely help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for the link below u will get ur ans here:

[Rotate View Hierarchy 90 degrees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444764/rotate-view-hierarchy-90-degrees)