# How to rotate a Button View in android

Tags: android

I want to rotate a Button view by 45 degrees. For that I have written the code which is shown below. Now rather than rotating the Button itself, the text or label on the Button is getting rotated. But I want the Button to get rotated by 45 degrees. How can I accomplish this?

```
public class MyButton extends Button {

    public float degrees;
    public float sWidth;
    public float sHeight;

    public MyButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        canvas.save();
        canvas.rotate(45.0f);
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.restore();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        sWidth=w;
        sHeight=h;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which API level are your targeting?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This link may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444764/rotate-view-hierarchy-90-degrees).

I believe you need to apply `RotateAnimation` to the view, with `fillAfter` set to true to keep it's angle. The above example works on the layout, but you could apply the animation to a view (in your case, the button).

Answer (score 3):

if you want to have an stable rotated Button use the following extended Button. Maybe you need `getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2`:

```
public class RotateButton extends Button{

    public RotateButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public RotateButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.save();
        canvas.rotate(45, getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }

}
```

and in your layout:

```
<com.samples.myapp.ui.RotateButton
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/MyBtn"
        android:padding="5dip" android:textColor="@color/darkGreen"
        android:textSize="16dip" android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"></com.samples.myapp.ui.RotateButton>
```

Comment: I have a image on the button. After i rotate the button with the code you provide the image edges get distorted and loss its sharpness.

Answer (score 1):

If you're happy to use an animation, on API >= 11, I would go for:

```
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(buttonView, "rotation", 0, 45).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to rotate the button and the text within it use android:rotation="angle by which you want to rotate" within the xml file for the button