# fake a View to portrait inside landscape-mode

Tags: android, view, canvas, rotation

I have an Activity in Landscape-Mode. Inside there is a Custom-Title-View aligned like this:

[image: Current View]

Is it possible to keep the landscape mode and 'fake' this one View into portrait-mode like this:
[image: desired View]

I have tried to overwrite my custom TitleView and put something like this to `draw(Canvas)`

```
 public class VerticalTitle extends Title{

      public draw(Canvas){
           canvas.save();
           canvas.rotate(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);
           // i tryed many translations, but get none to work
           canvas.translate(0, getHeight());
           super.draw(canvas);
           canvas.restore()
      }

      public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
           super.onMeasure(heightMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
           setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredHeight(), getMeasuredWidth());
      }
}
```

If it is on any interest, The TitleBar extends from RelativeLayout and has fixed height and fill_parent width

The setRotate parameter from View is not an option, because the app should stay compatible to 2.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to extend Text view And build your custom vertical TextView first see these two links for more details

1. [Vertical TextView](http://www.pocketmagic.net/?p=1625)
2. [Vertical rotated label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258275/vertical-rotated-label-in-android/7855852#7855852)

and after that in your Layout-land you can use this Xml file for your layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.yourpackage.CustomVerticalTextView
        android:layout_width="42dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello"
        android:background="#0000FF" />

</LinearLayout>
```

If you want to rotate the layout instead of rotating all of its children by 90 degrees use 
 LayoutAnimationController

see this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444764/rotate-view-hierarchy-90-degrees) for more details

Comment: It doesn't really, as the questioner want to rotate anything but the cameraPreview. I just want to rotate/transform the Custom View, and let the rest untouched

Comment: what's your custom view isn't the vertical text view?

Comment: finally it works with a merge of your Links. The problem was the fixed Size inside XML. I could render it without any problem to a FrameLayout of width and height= FILL_PARENT

Answer (score 1):

I have never done this but I found two other answers here on SO that show ways you might accomplish this.

The first one involves extending the TextView class, and is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7855852/1105376).  Since you want to do a whole view though, I think the next answer is better suited to your situation.

The other answer is to create an animation using rotation to deal with it.  That answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2888892/1105376).