# Rotate ad view with API 8

Tags: android, opengl-es, rotation, android-view

I am using OpenGL in a RenderSurface View in my android game. The Game uses landscape as screen orientation but I want to place the ad  90° rotated at the bottom of the phone. (As it would be if I use portrait as screen orientation)

This is the only way I can place the ad without making the game unplayable on small screens. I maneged to do this with:

`View.rotate(..)`

The problem is that this function is first available with the API Level 11.

- Is there any workaround to to this with API Level 8?
- I have already tried a rotate animation but touch events are not delivered correctly. (The 
  adview prevents a workaround)

I would reduce my user base dramatically if my game is only playable with Android 3.0.

Comment: So you want the ad to appear vertically such that the words are like a  book spine? Also it would help to know what Ad SDK you are using.

Comment: Have you tried rotate using Matrix OR layoutparams (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444764/rotate-view-hierarchy-90-degrees)?

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if you couldnt do something like this? Sorry I don't have the time to test :/

```
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);

layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

addContentView(layout, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);    

adView = new AdView(this);

layout.addView(adView, adParams);
```

Since you are adding a content view over the opengl surfaceview perhaps.... well anyways like I said, no time to test it. give it a shot?