# Animation when changing orientation

Tags: android, android-fragments, orientation

Is it possible to perform animation when changing orientation? I have two layout for portrait and landscape. I want to perform a custom animation when changing orientation. If it's possible, how can I do that?
In addition, when the screen change orientation, the children view rotate independently. For example, the textview rotates from left to right and the button rotate from right to left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to use to rotate layout by using [this sugesstion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444764/rotate-view-hierarchy-90-degrees). It's just simulation, and the orientation is seemed to have animation when changing. As Jansel mentioned, there not way to change orientation change animation. Thus, I just try to make something to everything look like that.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, there is no way to change orientation change animation, because this  behavior is not handled by your app, it is handled by Window Manager that take your screen and rebuild your view.