# How to set two animations to layouts and trigger it when the orientation changes?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I want my layout to animate and rotate 90 degrees (left/right) rather than creating a new xml layout for its landscape mode.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Animation when changing orientation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19789190/animation-when-changing-orientation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with adding this code to your onCreate() method. I could not able to try but this should work because it calls oncreate method also when changing the orientation.

```
if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation==Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        //insert your code here when it is portrait
    }
    else if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation==Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
        //insert your code here when it is landscape
    }
```