# How to tilt a child layout at some angle

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I've tried the custom view and tilt the image to 45 degree successfully but I want to tilt the whole child layoout at some angle so that whatever I'll add in that child layout will automactically tiled .. For reference please take a look at the attached picture [image]

even I have tried this code but it wont help

```
public class CustomLinear extends LinearLayout{
private Matrix mForward = new Matrix();
private Matrix mReverse = new Matrix();
private float[] mTemp = new float[2];

public CustomLinear(Context context) {
super(context);
}

public CustomLinear(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {

canvas.rotate(75, getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);

mForward = canvas.getMatrix();
mForward.invert(mReverse);
canvas.save();
canvas.setMatrix(mForward); // This is the matrix we need to use for
                                        // proper positioning of touch events
super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
canvas.restore();
invalidate();
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
event.setLocation(getWidth() - event.getX(), getHeight() - event.getY());
return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thing it is possible using **rotate animation**. you can apply animation on the whole child layout with **0 duration** in On_create.

Here is the animation code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <rotate
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:toDegrees="-90"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="0"
        android:fillAfter="true">
    </rotate>
```

You can set the rotation angle as per your need.

Then use given code in your Activity's onCreate,

```
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
  super.onCreate(b);
     setContentView(R.layout.myscreen);
     Animation rotate_anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotation);
     LayoutAnimationController anim_controller = new LayoutAnimationController(rotate_anim, 0);
     FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.MyScreen_ContentLayout);
     layout.setLayoutAnimation(anim_controller);
 }
```

Comment: that works fine .. but I am unable to apply the same technique with horizontal scroll as you can see these rows will be scrollable horizontally ..

Answer (score 1):

Make custom (tilted/rotated) xml views and call it all in the main view.

Also, take a look at the following link this may help you.

http://mindfreakconcepts.blogspot.com/2013/03/how-to-rotate-listview-items-in-android.html

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but from my understanding you have to use animation to get the effect that you want instead of draw. There is a similar thread, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444764/rotate-view-hierarchy-90-degrees?rq=1) that might be worth checking out.